# Problem Installing CommandT for Vim on Windows (can't find ruby.h)

Tags: vim

I'm trying to install CommandT for Vim on Windows. My setup:

OS: Windows 7
Vim: Cream installation of Vim (Vim 7.3 plus ruby support)
Ruby: rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p334.exe
Ruby dev kit: DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.1-20101214-1400-sfx.exe

I followed this guide http://rfbrazier.posterous.com/installing-the-command-t-vim-plugin-on-window, as well as the official CommandT installation screen cast. I've installed ruby and the dev kit successfully, and have verified the dev kit installation by installing the discount gem.

My problem is that when I try to generate the CommandT makefile, I get an error saying the script can't find ruby.h: "checking for ruby.h... no". No makefile, no CommandT :(

Any advice?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) which is basically the same as [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) but written in pure Vimscript. This means it neither requires Ruby support enabled in Vim nor does it require the compilation of some Ruby extension implemented in C.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. Download http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/66888/devkit-3.4.5r3-20091110.7z and install it according to INSTALL.txt from this 7z-file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gVim 7.2 on windows and want a Command-T bundle with the extension already compiled, get from the same source I use in my vimfiles repository: https://github.com/carlosedp/vimfiles/tree/master/bundle